# VSTO for Word: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: vb.net, vsto

In trying to read the current word (where the cursor is) of a word document in a VSTO add-in with the following code :

```
Public Class MyRibbon
    Private Sub MyRibbon_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As RibbonUIEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim mobjApp As Word.Application = New Word.Application
        Dim mobjRange As Word.Range

        Dim intCounter As Integer
        'mobjApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        'mobjRange = Nothing
        If mobjApp.Documents.Count = 0 Then
            'Exit Sub
        End If
        MsgBox("hehe" & mobjApp.Documents.Count)
        'With mobjApp.Selection
        Dim sText As String
        sText = mobjApp.Selection.Text
        If Trim(sText) = "" Or Len(Trim(sText)) = 1 Then
            mobjApp.Selection.Words.First.Select()
        End If
        sText = mobjApp.Selection.Text
        If Not Len(Trim(sText)) > 0 Then
            MsgBox("set your cursor on a word", vbInformation)
            Exit Sub
        End If
        'End With
        MsgBox(2)
        If mobjApp.Selection.Paragraphs.Count > 1 Then
            mobjRange = mobjApp.Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range
            mobjRange.Select()
        Else
            mobjRange = mobjApp.Selection.Range
        End If
        Dim a As String
        a = mobjRange.Text
        mobjRange.Copy()
        MsgBox(a)
        Clipboard.SetText(a)
    End Sub
End Class
```

It throws an excepetion `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`at the `sText = mobjApp.Selection.Text` line and I don't know what I am doing wrong. Haven't I already initialized mobjApp to a new instance ?

Comment: Because Selection is null (Nothing in VB.NET) ?

Comment: @Steve yes, but why ? I am selecting (marking) a word, before clicking the button, so there is a selection

Comment: _Dim mobjApp As Word.Application = New Word.Application_ This is another Word instance not the current one.

Comment: yes, figured it out, must add a new document. thank you